# The problem of installing packages in Atom in Ubuntu for python

Tags: python, package, atom-editor

I downloaded the Atom program from GitHub and when I tried to install the python package, I encountered the following error.

[error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LmRa.png)

But it should bring me options.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: [Also relevant.](https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/) Specifically `"Atom package management will stop working"`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.